# this.parentNode not working inside a dom

Tags: javascript

```js
getSelection = () => {
  console.log("this", this); //valid but empty json
  console.log("this.parentNode", this.parentNode); //<=undefined
}
document.querySelector('i.edit').addEventListener('click', getSelection, false);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="name" class="control-label">
          <p class="text-info">Alex<i class="icon-star"></i> </p>
        </label>
  <input type="text" class="edit-input" />
  <i class="fa fa-pencil edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.parentNode`

Comment: And `.parent()` is jQuery

Comment: @Satpal tried it, wrong answer

Comment: @LGSon without jQuery

Comment: jsfiddle please

Comment: @LGSon for some reason it is not working for me

Comment: Have you read my answer, don't use arrow function as it does not have its own `this`

Comment: You should have deleted the poor question

Comment: there is no way to figure out from the error that this is due to arrow function, only people already familiar with how events are passed to arrow functions can catch it, so it will be needed for people looking for the same issue in future, so tagging duplicate is most appropite thing to do. Thanks for deleting the answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use an arrow function, your `this` doesn't refer to the object.

Use the `event.target` property

```html
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">
              <p class="text-info">Alex<i class="icon-star"></i> </p>
            </label>
      <input type="text" class="edit-input" />
      <i class="fa fa-pencil edit" aria-hidden="true">edit</i>
    </div>

    <script>
      getSelection = (e) => {
        //console.log("this", this); //valid but empty json
        console.log("e.target.parentNode", e.target.parentNode); //<=undefined
      }
      document.querySelector('i.edit').addEventListener('click', getSelection, false);
    </script>
```